# For loop - insert blank rows in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, loops, for-loop, insert

I am looking to insert blank records into a table to get a final value of 57,816,000 records. I am starting with a table of 550 unique identifiers and for each distinct TMC name and i want to add 105,119 records for each distinct value. So each TMC would have 105,120 records. (105,119 * 550 = 57,815,450 (+ original 550 = 57,816,000))

However, the problem i am having is an error within TOAD saying this.

ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 10272
Session ID: 247 Serial number: 1959
Script will end

It works on a small scale but i suspect its not the best way to go. Below is my script. Any advice?

```
declare i number(10) :=1;

begin

for i in 1..105119

Loop
insert into npmrds_dummy 
select distinct tmc,
travel_time_passenger_vehicles,
travel_time_freight_trucks,
travel_time_all_vehicles,
road_number,
road_name,
epoch,
distance,
date1,
admin_level_1,
admin_level_2,
admin_level_3

 from npmrds_dummy;

end loop;
end;
```

Comment: My apologies. I am using TOAD for Oracle 12.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with one SQL statement:

```
insert into npmrds_dummy 
      select  npmrds_dummy.*
      from    npmrds_dummy
      inner join ( select 1 from dual connect by level <= 105119 )
```

The join with the sub select is [a neat trick](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques#CONNECT_BY_LEVEL) to multiply the number of records.

As at the start your records are unique, there is no need for the `distinct`, and you can just do `select npmrds_dummy.*`.

Comment: outstanding. Thank you for your help. This has been a great learning experience for me as well.

Comment: Another question. Ive been reading that committing after so many records is not ideal but i am dealing with some constraints with temporary tablespace. Is this an option for a SQL statement such as this?

Comment: You can maybe use the `append` hint to enforce "direct-load" inserts, as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58227/ch_dlins.htm#880). Quote: *"A major benefit of direct-load INSERT is that you can load data without logging redo or undo entries"*

Comment: My next statement was using the minus feature because
I am trying to keep all of the 57.8mil records but fill the rows in npmrds_2 that have data in from the npmrds_2015

Since it is a one to many relationship, merge or upsert wasnt working but i was able to get the minus function to work on a smaller dataset but now gives me an out of memory. basically, updating the larger blank data set with data while keeping all rows.

Comment: You have a new question? May I suggest creating a new question for it?